# Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $ in retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit

I got this error when trying to get data from **API** using **retrofit**.

**Model**

```
public class Movie {
    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private Integer id;
    @SerializedName("title")
    @Expose
    private String title;
    @SerializedName("image")
    @Expose
    private String image;
    @SerializedName("link")
    @Expose
    private String link;
    @SerializedName("description")
    @Expose
    private String description;
    @SerializedName("category")
    @Expose
    private String category;
    @SerializedName("actor")
    @Expose
    private String actor;
    @SerializedName("director")
    @Expose
    private String director;
    @SerializedName("manufacturer")
    @Expose
    private String manufacturer;
    @SerializedName("duration")
    @Expose
    private String duration;
    @SerializedName("year")
    @Expose
    private String year;
    @SerializedName("created_at")
    @Expose
    private String createdAt;
    @SerializedName("updated_at")
    @Expose
    private String updatedAt;
    @SerializedName("views")
    @Expose
    private Integer views;
    @SerializedName("type")
    @Expose
    private String type;
    //get and set....
}
```

**APIservice.class**

```
@Headers("app_token:dCuW7UQMbdvpcBDfzolAOSGFIcAec11a")
@POST("training-movie/movie/list")
Call<List<Movie>> getMovie();
```

**MainActivity**

```
  Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(" http://dev.bsp.vn:8081/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .client(oBuilder.build())
        .build();

APIService service = retrofit.create(APIService.class);

Call<List<Movie>> call = service.getMovie();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Movie>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Movie>> call, Response<List<Movie>> response) {
            if(response.isSuccessful()){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+response.body().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Movie>> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

I got error here, I think I'm not understand how retrofit work. Someone can tell me more about it.

Update: JSON

```
{
    "error": false,
    "code": 0,
    "message": "",
    "paging": {
        "total_item": 31,
        "per_page": 10,
        "current_page": 1,
        "total_pages": 4
    },
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "DON'T BREATHE / SÁT NHÂN TRONG BÓNG TỐI",
            "image": "http://dev.bsp.vn:8081/training-movie/upload/movie/sdasdasda.jpg",
            "link": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TRusW3VPLaI",
            "description": "Ba tên trộm liều lĩnh đột nhập vào nhà một người đàn ông giàu có bị mù. Lũ trộm cho rằng bản thân sẽ vớ bở, thế nhưng chúng đã sai. Trong bóng tối, kẻ mù làm vua. Người đàn ông tưởng chừng yếu đuối nay lại trở thành ác quỷ đưa bọn chúng xuống địa ngục.",
            "category": "Kinh dị, Hành động",
            "actor": "Daniel Zovatto, Jane Levy",
            "director": "Fede Alvarez",
            "manufacturer": "Sony Pictures",
            "duration": "88",
            "year": "2016-08-30",
            "created_at": "2016-08-30 15:45:37",
            "updated_at": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
            "views": 896,
            "type": "showing"
        }
    ]
}
```

Update: model

```
public class Data {

    @SerializedName("error")
    @Expose
    private Boolean error;
    @SerializedName("code")
    @Expose
    private Integer code;
    @SerializedName("message")
    @Expose
    private String message;
    @SerializedName("paging")
    @Expose
    private Paging paging;
    @SerializedName("data")
    @Expose
    private List<Movie> data = null;

public class Paging {

    @SerializedName("total_item")
    @Expose
    private Integer totalItem;
    @SerializedName("per_page")
    @Expose
    private Integer perPage;
    @SerializedName("current_page")
    @Expose
    private Integer currentPage;
    @SerializedName("total_pages")
    @Expose
    private Integer totalPages;
```

Comment: post your json.

Comment: sorry, i forgot

Comment: Check my answer. just copy paste your json to that site

Comment: post second model instead of this. which uses this

Comment: The json that you get in your response is formatted in a specific way and that format is not being match by you in code, the moment you give us the json, we can give you a proper answer.

Comment: @VishvaDave i just posted it

Comment: @HảiSơn Check my answer. generate model class from there and replace it once.

Comment: @VishvaDave i changed, and what's function i can use in APIService class, i dont know

Comment: @HảiSơn you need to print the `whole`  data ?

Comment: It's work now, thank you very much, it's my bad :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to fetch Data class as an object as follows

**ApiService**

```
@Headers("app_token:dCuW7UQMbdvpcBDfzolAOSGFIcAec11a")
@POST("training-movie/movie/list")
Call<Data> getMovie();
```

**MainActivity**

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(" http://dev.bsp.vn:8081/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .client(oBuilder.build())
        .build();

APIService service = retrofit.create(APIService.class);

Call<Data> call = service.getMovie();
call.enqueue(new Callback<Data>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<Data> call, Response<Data> response) {
        if(response.isSuccessful()){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+response.body().getData().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<Data> call, Throwable t) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
});
```

And change **Data** class like this

```
public class Data {

@SerializedName("error")
@Expose
private Boolean error;
@SerializedName("code")
@Expose
private Integer code;
@SerializedName("message")
@Expose
private String message;
@SerializedName("paging")
@Expose
private Paging paging;
@SerializedName("data")
@Expose
private List<Movie> data = null;
public List<Movie> getData() {
return data;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a class called response

```
public class Response {

public boolean error;
public int code;
public String message;
public List<Movie> data;

}
```

Modify your api service class function so it looks like this

```
Call<Response> getMovie();
```

Here Response is the class you created above. This should work.

P.S. your app token is compromised, please consider changing it and for future events do not post any sensitive data such as keys, tokens etc on stack overflow.

Comment: my response.body().toString()  is   


com.example.hscoraline.retrofit_example.model.Response@6bf8c01

Answer (score 0):

In your Retrofit call method
Use this

```
Call<Data> call = service.getMovie();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Data>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Data> call, Response<Data> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + response.body().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Data> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Instead of

```
Call<List<Movie>> call = service.getMovie();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Movie>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Movie>> call, Response<List<Movie>> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + response.body().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Movie>> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

You Didn't use the Base class of Response it Should be `Data` but you are using `List<Movie>`